# Can looking at a computer screen be good for your eyes?

Tags: eye, computers, benefits, screen-time-limits

Let's put aside harmful affects of staring at computer screen, is there any advantage of looking at computer screen for long time ?

The reason that I ask this question is this: My mother and father both did not use computer when they were young and they had sight has problems when they were around 22-23 years old, and started using eyeglasses.

On the other hand I have been looking at computers since I am 6 years old, I became a computer engineer and my life is looking at computers. Now I am 31 years old and I don't use glasses and don't have any problem with my eyes.

Even though I am genetically prone to, I did not suffer any problems. Could there be a relationship ? Or am I genetically lucky?

Comment: Without having any expertise or conducting research in this area, I'd say no. My parents do have glasses, and so do I, but my vision is a lot better. This is more likely to be the case because myopia et al. is diagnosed earlier and treated earlier, and therefore eyesight doesn't decrease as quickly. I suppose that something similar might be the case with your Szenario as well. Correlation, not causation.

Comment: +! for correlation not causation statement.  Actually I meant +1 but the ! does appropriately relay my sentiments in seeing you say that, so I'll keep it.